# Gulp run function doesn't appear to be working

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

/app

index.html

--/sass

----style.scss

--/css

----style.css

Gulp CLI version **2.0.1** and Local version **4.0.0**

Running `gulp sass` correctly runs the sass function and compiles my sass file.
Running `gulp sass:watch` starts the watch...

[image: images of gulp watch running]

If I change some styles within the style.scss and save the file I get:

[image]

but no changes are propagated to css/style.css.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/sass/style.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/'))
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./app/sass/*.scss', gulp.series(sass));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of `.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/'))`, can you please try this, `.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/style.css'))`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Code_Ninja. I tried your suggestion but still not working.

Comment: are you sure that you have successfully installed the sass module?

Comment: I think so? I can run the sass function directly and it compiles fine. Only the watch function is causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if think you just forgot two ' around 'sass' in gulp.series

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/sass/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css/'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./app/sass/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
});
```